# Dúvida no padrão MVC: um serviço deve conversar com outro diretamente?

Tags: mvc, services

É correto um serviço conversar com outro diretamente atraves de injeção de dependência, ou quem deve gerenciar essa comunicação é a controller.

Ex.: Tenho um serviço(A) que precisa de um dado obtido por outro serviço(B), devo injetar o serviço B no serviço A ou o correto seria a controller injetar o serviço A e o serviço B, obter o dado que preciso do serviço (B), através da conotroller e passar para o Serviço (A)?